# MVC Post request not working in Edge/IE, but works in FF & Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cross-browser

My MVC5 website is hosted in IIS 8.5 (Azure VM).

For some reason my `POST` Request code works when using Firefox or Chrome. But is responding with a HTTP 500 (internal server error) when using Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge!

Previously when the 'Site' was an 'Application' located under the Default Website, during the development phase, it was working. Once I moved it as a Site, the POST code no longer works!

Something to note, when running the code within Visual Studio with ANY of these browsers works well!

**I've spent a day investigating and trying to get it to work. Can anyone see if there is anything wrong with the code, or am I missing something in IIS?**

Below is the code stripped down to it's absolute minimum, and the problem is still happening...

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Click Me" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
 }
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    // Striped down code to 1 line that can't go wrong!
    return RedirectToAction("About");
}
```

**Route config**

Very much default...

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Error page**

Resolved this today (8/11/2015). Simply adding /Shared/Error.cshtml resolves the missing error page. Note sure why this:

```
<error statusCode="500" path="/Error/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

doesn't handle ALL 500 errors. I read (apparently) that HandleError Attribute requires the /Shared/Error.cshtml page.

I cannot obtain the root cause of the 500 error. I only get the standard 500 error Detail page merely suggesting what could possibly be the problem. **Anyone know how to get the reason for the exception?**

Comment: The HTTP `500` error will have an associated error message. What is it? Try and debug your application and see what is happening in the `Test()` method.

Comment: Please show the route config and the controller details.

Comment: @JamieR No useful details with the 500 error other than the standard spiel. I.e. I changed web.config to output Detail error (from Custom error).

Comment: @D.Rosado Updated Question with further info. ActionMethod only has 1 line which works in FF and Chrome.